# Не выполняется условие в if/else

Tags: java

В данной части кода пользователю необходимо ввести номер банковской карты, а программа должна проверить, чтобы он соответствовал шаблону XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. Я разделяю строку CardNumber на 4 подстроки и проверяю, чтобы кол-во этих подстрок равнялось 4 и кол-во символов в каждой подстроке тоже равнялось 4. Если я все правильно понимаю, то кол-во подстрок - это subCardNumber.length, а сами подстроки и их длина - это элементы массива subCardNumber[]. Если хотя бы одно из этих условий неверно, должна выйти ошибка, однако, какие бы неправильные номера карт я не вводил, всегда выдается сообщение, что номер карты верный, т.е. выполняется только условие else. Вот сам код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Здравствуйте. Введите номер карты:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String CardNumber = sc.nextLine();
            String[] subCardNumber;
            String delimeter = "-";
            subCardNumber = CardNumber.split(delimeter);
            if (subCardNumber.length != 4 & subCardNumber[0].length() != 4 & subCardNumber[1].length() != 4 & subCardNumber[2].length() != 4 & subCardNumber[3].length() != 4)
                System.out.println("Ошибка. Введите верный номер карты:");
            else System.out.println("Верный номер карты");
        }
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Замените все "&" в условии, на "|"

Comment: “Хотя бы одно” это ИЛИ, а у вас в коде И, что означает  "все".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, очевидно, в логическом И, нужно использовать логическое ИЛИ, если вы ожидаете хотя бы одну ошибку. В данном случае, ваше исправление такое:

```
if (subCardNumber.length != 4 | subCardNumber[0].length() != 4 | subCardNumber[1].length() != 4 | subCardNumber[2].length() != 4 | subCardNumber[3].length() != 4)
```

Но, как по мне, ваш способ решения немного усложненный, как на счёт использования регулярных выражений?

С регулярными выражениями всё в разы упрощается и выглядит так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Здравствуйте. Введите номер карты:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String CardNumber = sc.nextLine();
    if (Pattern.matches("^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$", CardNumber))
        System.out.println("Верный номер карты");
    else System.out.println("Ошибка. Введите верный номер карты:");
}
```

Как вам такой вариант? :)

Comment: Может, лучше использовать сокращённое или `||`? Оптимизация, все дела.

Comment: спасибо, it worked:)